# KendoUI-Angular2 Chart component responsivity

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

I have two issues relative to the Chart component:

- my x-axis labels are months, but they overlap each other. Is there a way to avoid that ?

[image]

- If I rotate my device to landscape orientation, the chart does not adapt to the new size. See screenshot. How do I fix that ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use automatic label rotation as in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Bjm8xsCIgviOJHUFlwN4?p=preview):

```
<kendo-chart>
  <kendo-chart-category-axis>
    <kendo-chart-category-axis-item [labels]="{ rotation: 'auto' }">
    </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
  </kendo-chart-category-axis>
</kendo-chart>
```

As for the second issue, you can monitor [issue #73](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/73) for updates.

Comment: With the latest version(0.8.0) I've this error now:

```Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "../../../../kendo-angular-resize-sensor/dist/npm/js/resize-sensor.component.ngfactory"
```

It was working with the previous one(0.7.4)

Comment: First issue was solved using the automatic label rotation indeed. After installing 0.0.8 I'm also having the error `Could not resolve                                                                                                                                             
            '../../../../kendo-angular-resize-sensor/dist/npm/js/resize-sensor.component.ngfactory' from                                                                                 
            C:\dev\ecdt-mobile\.tmp\node_modules\@progress\kendo-angular-charts\dist\npm\js\chart.component.ngfactory.js`

Comment: Oh the wonders of SystemJS. I've updated the snippet with the updated config.